# how to convert the given code in go templating

Tags: go, go-templates

I am using `go`'s `text/template`. I want to do something like:

```
method = some_var
path = some_other_var    
if method is "GET" and "ID" in path
```

How can I do this in a go template? I am doing it like this.

```
{{- if and eq .Method "GET" contains "AssetID" .OperationId -}}
```

EDIT:

The thing is I am working with [openAPI](https://github.com/deepmap/oapi-codegen)  to generate a server-code boilerplate. So the templates are in that repo. I am doing it something like:

```
$ go get github.com/deepmap/oapi-codegen/cmd/oapi-codegen
$ oapi-codegen \
    -templates my-templates/ \
    -generate types,server \
    example-expanded.yaml
```

above oapi-codegen line is [here](https://github.com/deepmap/oapi-codegen#making-changes-to-code-generation).
my-templates contains the templates I have changed. These are also provided by `oapi-codegen`. [this](https://github.com/deepmap/oapi-codegen/tree/master/pkg/codegen/templates) dir contains them and I have copied and changed a few of them and followed the steps as directed [here](https://github.com/deepmap/oapi-codegen#making-changes-to-code-generation).

in one of those templates that I changed, I want to use `contains`. 
What would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no builtin `contains` function in templates, so you have to register your function for that. You may use the [`strings.Contains()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Contains) function from the standard lib. For reference, the available builtin template functions are listed here: [Functions](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Functions)

And you have to group the params of the `eq` and `contains` like this:

```
{{if and (eq .Method "GET") (contains .AssetID .OperationId)}}
    true
{{else}}
    false
{{end}}
```

Example code to register the `strings.Contains()` function, parse the template and execute it:

```
t := template.Must(template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
    "contains": strings.Contains,
}).Parse(src))

params := map[string]interface{}{
    "Method":      "GET",
    "AssetID":     "/some/path/123",
    "OperationId": "123",
}
if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, params); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

params["OperationId"] = "xxx"
if err := t.Execute(os.Stdout, params); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/M47u1Q2-aXZ)):

```
true

false
```

Comment: is there any other way without registering this function?

Comment: @rayan Yes, if the values have methods, then you can call those methods without registering any functions.

Comment: hey, I made an edit to the question. would u please have a look. I am sorry u might need to do a bit of reading.

Comment: @rayan I'm not familiar with those templates, but looks some of them is used to generate Go code, which means in those you could write any valid Go code, including using `strings.Contains()`.